# Get the value instead of key with Laravel collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-collection

```
$job_types = DB::table('jobs')->pluck('job_type')->unique();
```

Upper code return a collection as below.

[image]

Also below Laravel Blade code make select list with upper collection.

```
<!-- Job Type Field -->
<div class="form-group col-sm-4" >
    {!! Form::label('job_type', 'Emne:') !!}        
    {!! Form::select('job_type', $job_types, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'job_type']) !!}
</div>
```

This is return view as select box.
[image]

So my goal was post selected value in the select box.
but I got these keys like 0, 2, 17, 6 as value in the DB.
I got still only **KEY** instead of **Value**.

How could I get the value to insert data into DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply give the second parameter to the pluck method:

```
$job_types = DB::table('jobs')->pluck('job_type', 'job_type')->unique();
```

However, I think you should reconsider the practice of storing the value as it may result in [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) violations.

Comment: @your answer was very useful, and how to avoid "database normalization" in my case?:)

Comment: one thing you can do first would be to avoid duplicate entries. That being said I think that these job types should belong to an separate table.The jobs tables should have an foreign key referencing the job_tyoes table through the column job_type_id

Answer (score 1):

See: https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#drop-down-lists

```
Form::select('size', array('L' => 'Large', 'S' => 'Small'));
```

Array keys will be taken as value of `select`.

So, your problem is your `$job_types` array is not formatted right with your request.

If you want to get `job_type` as `select` value, make sure that they are `$job_types` key.

Change:

`$job_types = DB::table('jobs')->pluck('job_type')->unique();`

to

`$job_types = DB::table('jobs')->pluck('job_type', 'job_type')->unique();`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and explanation.
I gave accepance of answer to Matei  because the same answer came out first.:)

Answer (score 0):

Use `groupBy()`:

```
$job_types = DB::table('jobs')->groupBy('job_type')->pluck('job_type');
```

Comment: it's not correctly worked. I use above code, thanks.